# Display Custom Post Type w/ Custom Taxonomy Using Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to display a custom post type (testimonials) along with a specific taxonomy term using a shortcode. Right now the shortcode is displaying all posts from the testimonials custom post type instead of the targeted taxonomy term.

This is the shortcode I think I'm meant to use:

```
[list-testimonials terms="37"]
```

In order to execute the following PHP:

```
// create shortcode with parameters so that the user can define what's queried     
add_shortcode( 'list-testimonials', 'post_listing_parameters_shortcode' );
function post_listing_parameters_shortcode( $atts ) {
ob_start();

// define attributes and their defaults
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'type' => 'testimonials',
    'order' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts' => -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'testimonial-category',
), $atts ) );

// define query parameters based on attributes
$options = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'order' => $order,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'taxonomy_name' => $terms,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $options );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

**THE HTML OUTOUT**

<?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable; 
}
}
```

I think I'm really close. What am I missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just remove `post_type` from your query? [Querying by taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see where removing the post_type in the query makes sense given that the function I've created is meant to only pull from that specific post type anyways. When I remove post_type the output on the page does change but not exactly for the better. Now it is displaying 2 posts but they aren't the right IDs and it is not pulling over any content of the post - just one div that has a background image.